# How do I get the value of 0b011 from the primary oscillator with PLL in a DSPIC33FJ128GP710A

Tags: microcontroller, pic

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70593d.pdf, here is the link for the data sheet it explains in section 9 as to configure COSC<2:0> of OSCCON register to one of the following. I am using primary oscillator with PLL it is represented as 011 as shown below. But when in code it is written as OSCCONbits.COSC!=0b011. I want know in value 0b011, I think that 011 represents the primary oscillator with PLL, but what is 0b which is attached as prefix to the value.

bit 14-12 COSC<2:0>: Current Oscillator Selection bits (read-only)

```
                111 = Fast RC oscillator (FRC) with Divide-by-N
                110 = Fast RC oscillator (FRC) with Divide-by-16
                101 = Low-Power RC oscillator (LPRC)
                100 = Secondary oscillator (Sosc)
                011 = Primary oscillator (XT, HS, EC) with PLL
                010 = Primary oscillator (XT, HS, EC)
               001 = Fast RC Oscillator (FRC) with Divide-by-N and PLL (FRCDIVN +PLL)
                000 = Fast RC oscillator (FRC)
```

Comment: Just a little note: the expression "OSCCONbits.COSC!=0b011" doesn't actually set the COSC bits to a value of 011. Its asking the question "are the COSC bits set to anything other than 011", returning a 1/0 (yes/no) result and leaving the COSC bits unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

The value `0b011` represents the *binary* value `011`, which equates to decimal 3.

The `0b` signifies that the following digits are in base 2, or binary.

This notation was popular in a number of compilers, like GCC, and has since been adopted as [part of the new C++14 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Binary_literals).

It follows the same kind of syntax as using `0x...` for hexadecimal.